# How do I finish a ridge cap?

Tags: installation, roofing, shingles

I've installed the ridge cap, using modified 3 tab shingles.

[image]

I've installed the ridge cap all the way to the other end of the ridge, but I'm not quite sure what to do now.

[image]

The next shingle will be hanging out over nothingness, how can I nail it down?

<sub>*Please don't nitpick about not using Ridge Cap Shingles, that's a [different question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/16766/33) altogether.*</sub>

Comment: I won't nitpick. IMO cutting down tabbed shingles is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what I've done in similar situations. Cut off the top half of the shingle (using the piece without the glue line) and 2-4 nails right through your last shingle. Cover the nails with a drop of roof cement.

Answer (score 3):

Nail down, through the tar strip the dark grey shingle in your image.

Cut a new piece in half, throwing out the half with the tar strip.

Glue down the cut shingle with roofing cement. Remember to cover the nail heads from the last step.

I believe you can buy roofing cement in a caulking tube if you don't happen to have any left over.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a roofing expert but I put plenty of shingles on back in the day. My grandfather was a building contractor so I learned the techniques over the years. First of all, we NEVER used staples...ever, 4 nails to a shingle and they don't blow off in storms!! We turn the first row of shingles upside down at the drip edge then start the next row right side up right over the starter edge. Continue up the roof from both side and then cut 3 caps from each tab of the shingle. Using the tabs we started at one end working toward the other so the nails were blind and then on the last tab you have to nail it and use some roof cement on the nail neads. Gluing anything on a roof isn't in our vocabulary!!! NAILS and NAILS ONLY!!! We also removed old shingles and reshingled.....NO three layer roofs ever!! There's such a thing as doing it right the first time or doing a half azz job and redoing it over and over!!