# What advantages do ridge cap shingles have over modified 3-tab shingles?

Tags: roofing, shingles

I'm preparing to re shingle my roof. I'm not sure if I should use ridge cap shingles,

[image]

or simply cut up 3-tab shingles for the ridge cap.

[image]

Do ridge cap shingles have any advantages over modified 3-tab shingles?

Comment: I think it's a matter of convenience.  Also, every cut you make is potentially a cut to your fingers.  The likelihood of war wounds is greatly reduced if you buy them pre-cut.

Comment: the Q makes is sound like you're considering a 3-tab reroof: in which case you might be thinking in terms of conferring an advantage at the ridge upon a distinct disadvantage in the field. With the relatively rapid "aging" of tab shingles, would the cost of much more durable ridge cap shingles be money well spent?

Comment: I would be inclined to think also, that the aesthetic advantages of ridge cap shingles might call unwanted attention to the comparative ... paltriness of a single-ply, tab-shingled roof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Less chance of cracking

Standard shingles are a bit thinner than ridge cap shingles, and can crack or tear when folded over the ridge.  Ridge cap shingles are thicker and come pre-bent, so there is less chance of cracking.

## Better adhesion

Most ridge cap shingles have an extra dollop of adhesive near the end of the shingle, to help hold it to the shingle below. This helps to prevent blow off in heavy winds.

## Thicker nailing surface

Ridge cap shingles have a thicker nailing area, which helps prevent tearing near nail holes.

## No extra prep

Since ridge cap shingles are designed specifically for the ridge, there is not preparation required. Just open the box, and start slapping them on.

Answer (score 0):

I've always did what the homeowner wants and can afford. I live in ky (originally from Milwaukee so I brought the quality workmanship with me) so the weather stays relatively warm all yr...considering where im from..so cracking three tab isn't really an issue... If anything think run another strip of tar from a caulk gun 2" from the end and never worry about wind bringing them up...takes more but it works